# Finding individual sums of all possible tree after removing edges

Tags: c++, algorithm, performance, tree, time-complexity

Given a tree with N nodes with non-zero weights of nodes, how many trees (removing one or more edge) of this tree will have sum of weights as x (given)?

For example :

N = 3, weight of each vertex is 1 1 1 , x=2

edges

1 2

2 3

now removing 1-2 we have 2 trees 1 and 2-3 with sum of weights 1 and 2 respectively, we remove edge 2-3, we have 1-2 and 3 with sum as 2 and 1 
so there are total 2 trees among all possible trees(after removing one or more edge) with sum of weight equals to 2.

My Solution-:

I am only able to come up with a brute force solution with complexity 2^n (where n can be as large as 10^5).

Brute Force -: cut each edge and apply bfs/dfs to all the trees that are formed and add the respective weights of vertex and check if the sum is equal to x.

I think this can be optimized using DP memoization but i am not able to come up with a recurrence relation.

I tried min-cut algorithm too but it's not applicable here as much as i understand.

```
int bfs()
{
    for(each cut in 2^n using bitmask)
    {
        queue <int> q;
        q.push(s);
        vis[ s ] = true;
        while(!q.empty())
        {
            int p = q.front();
            q.pop();
            for(int i = 0;i < v[ p ].size() ; i++)
            {
                if(vis[ v[ p ][ i ] ] == false)
                {
                    sum+=w[p][i]; // weight of p-i edge is w[p][i]                  
                    q.push(v[ p ][ i ]);
                    vis[ v[ p ][ i ] ] = true;
                }
            }        
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any better algorithm/optimization of above 2^n solution, according to the question there is O(n) or O(n*logn) solution is possible.

If there is any better way you can suggest please provide or if there is some tree cut algorithm that is required here please suggest.

Comment: I guess you can have `O(n^3)` (also some kind of brute force by traverse the tree and set weight for all sub-tree from him and then return it or reduce 2 other sub tree

Comment: @dWinder i need O(n) or O(nlogn), O(n^3) will run out of time because n is as large as 10^5 and time is 1 sec only and i guess 10^7 operation can be done in 1 sec at max